# Передать аналоговый сигнал A0 от Arduino NodeMCU в приложение Android (Android Studio)

Tags: android, wifi, arduino, nodemcu

Подскажите, как по Wi-fi передать значение сигнала аналогового порта А0 в Android NodeMCU, используя протокол UDP.
В интернете много информации об управлении цифровыми портами, а об этом ничего не нашел.
Я создал скейтч из примеров Arduino WifiWebServer и выводил данные в браузер и в монитор порта, а надо передать в приложение на Android Studio для дальнейшей обработки.
Заранее спасибо.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

#ifndef STASSID
#define STASSID "111"
#define STAPSK  "222"
#endif

const char* ssid = STASSID;
const char* password = STAPSK;

WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.print(F("Connecting to "));
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(F("."));
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("WiFi connected"));
  server.begin();
  Serial.println(F("Server started"));
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {

  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }
  while (client.available()) {
    // byte by byte is not very efficient
    client.read();
  }
  client.print(String(analogRead(A0)));
  Serial.println(F("Disconnecting from client"));
}
```

Comment: Приложение Android может получать данные по http, т.е. через web, как обычный браузер

Comment: Это я и так знаю. Ответ не по существу.

Comment: Это не ответ, а комментарий. Я просто боюсь, что вы ответа на свой вопрос не дождетесь, потому что в нем не хватает конкретики. Например где относительно ардуины находится андроид, в той же WiFi сети или где то в интернете. Требуется ли поиск устройства или его ip адрес известен (указан явно в приложении). Как бы приложение хотело получать эти данные, по запросу или что бы устройство само их периодически слало. Почему именно по UDP. Что именно вызывает сложности, код ардуины для работы с UDP или код на андроиде ? Или общие вопросы по организации взаимодействия

Comment: Спасибо, за разъяснения.

Comment: Спасибо, за разъяснения, попробую уточнить. 
Проблема в том, что многие давно пытаются вытянуть аналоговый сигнал из платы Arduino не на веб-сервер (это неудобно обрабатывать), а напрямую в приложение. Оптимальная связь - напрямую, без участия интернета и роутера, т.к. ESP может быть и точкой доступа, и сервером и клиентом. На крайний случай с роутером по локалке. IP известен и мы его можем задать в коде - задача лежит в локальном подключении - увидеть показания сигнала A0 (Arduino), стоя рядом с телефоном. 
Устройство само шлет данные, без запроса, пока включено.

Comment: UDP - потому что NodeMCU на нем общаются и он проще, чем HTTP. 
Я могу передать данные по UDP с одной NodeMCU на другую. Всего NodeMCU - 2 шт. 1-я шлет данные 2-й с А0, 2-я добавляет свой А0 и должна передать обе А0 на телефон.
Как передать это в браузер через HTTP - в нэте полно инфы, но я не могу подхватить эти данные для дальнейшей обработки.
Проблема со стороны Androida - как получить данные. На Arduino код работает.

Comment: Вариант "запрос - ответ" тоже, конечно интересен. На данном этапе можно задать простой запрос.

Comment: Я далект от андроида, так что мне подсказывает гугл. http://findevelop.blogspot.com/2013/11/udp-android.html вот пример примема и передачи UDP на андроиде. Я специально нашел что то с broadcast потому как предполагаю, что ардуина изначально не знает ip андроида. На основе этого предлагаю такой протокол: Андроид когда хочет начать получать данные шлет броадкаст пакет с каким то магическим содержимым (Например "Hello nMCU") . Ардуина слушает постоянно этот порт  и запоминает ip адреса тех кто это прислал. После чего рассылает периодически на эти адреса данные. Пока не получит пакет "Bye nMCU"

Comment: Хотя можно вообще тупо "в лоб", ардуина постоянно шлет показания UDP на широковещательный адрес, на заранее оговоренный порт. Андроиды  слушают этот порт.

Comment: Но если приложение все таки в интернете, а не в локалнке, то первый вариант с Hello запросами (Только на известный ip, на не броадкаст) конечно интереснее. Но на такой случае в "интернете вещей" часто используют протокол MQTT (он на UDP основан). Тут чуть сложнее, где то надо поднять брокер (сервер), NodeMCU сливают на него данные, а андроиды подписываются на рассыли и их получают. Кстати гугл по этому поводу (запрос "NodeMCU MQTT") рассказал много интересного, например https://habr.com/ru/post/326794/